# What is "destroying operator delete" in C++20?

Tags: c++, destructor, c++20, delete-operator, destroy

C++20 introduced "destroying [`operator delete`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_delete)": new overloads of `operator delete` that take a tag-type [`std::destroying_delete_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/destroying_delete_t) parameter.

What exactly is this and when is it useful?

Comment: This post is being discussed on meta in [Why is this c++ question which asks “what destroying operator deletes does” an acceptable question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/407773/why-is-this-c-question-which-asks-what-destroying-operator-deletes-does-an-a)

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66511829/is-destroying-form-of-operator-delete-required-to-actually-destroy-the-object

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Prior to C++20, objects' destructors were always called prior to calling their `operator delete`. With destroying `operator delete` in C++20, `operator delete` can instead call the destructor itself. Here's a very simple toy example of non-destroying vs. destroying `operator delete`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <new>

struct Foo {
    ~Foo() {
        std::cout << "In Foo::~Foo()\n";
    }

    void operator delete(void *p) {
        std::cout << "In Foo::operator delete(void *)\n";
        ::operator delete(p);
    }
};

struct Bar {
    ~Bar() {
        std::cout << "In Bar::~Bar()\n";
    }

    void operator delete(Bar *p, std::destroying_delete_t) {
        std::cout << "In Bar::operator delete(Bar *, std::destroying_delete_t)\n";
        p->~Bar();
        ::operator delete(p);
    }
};

int main() {
    delete new Foo;
    delete new Bar;
}
```

And the output:

```
In Foo::~Foo()
In Foo::operator delete(void *)
In Bar::operator delete(Bar *, std::destroying_delete_t)
In Bar::~Bar()
```

Key facts about it:

- A destroying `operator delete` function must be a class member function.
- If more than one `operator delete` is available, a destroying one will always take precedence over a non-destroying one.
- The difference between the signatures of non-destroying and destroying `operator delete` is that the former receives a `void *`, and the latter receives a pointer to the type of the object being deleted and a dummy `std::destroying_delete_t` parameter.
- Like non-destroying `operator delete`, destroying `operator delete` can also take an optional `std::size_t` and/or `std::align_val_t` parameter, in the same way. These mean the same thing they always did, and they go after the dummy `std::destroying_delete_t` parameter.
- The destructor is not called prior to the destroying `operator delete` running, so it is expected to do so itself. This also means that the object is still valid and can be examined prior to doing so.
- With non-destroying `operator delete`, calling `delete` on a derived object through a pointer to a base class without a virtual destructor is Undefined Behavior. This can be made safe and well-defined by giving the base class a destroying `operator delete`, since its implementation can use other means to determine the correct destructor to call.

Use-cases for destroying `operator delete` were detailed in [P0722R1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0722r1.html). Here's a quick summary:

- Destroying `operator delete` allows classes with variable-sized data at the end of them to retain the performance advantage of sized `delete`. This works by storing the size within the object, and retrieving it in `operator delete` before calling the destructor.
- If a class will have subclasses, any variable-sized data allocated at the same time must go before the start of the object, rather than after the end. In this case, the only safe way to `delete` such an object is destroying `operator delete`, so that the correct starting address of the allocation can be determined.
- If a class only has a few subclasses, it can implement its own dynamic dispatch for the destructor this way, instead of needing to use a vtable. This is slightly faster and results in a smaller class size.

Here's an example of the third use case:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <new>

struct Shape {
    const enum Kinds {
        TRIANGLE,
        SQUARE
    } kind;

    Shape(Kinds k) : kind(k) {}

    ~Shape() {
        std::cout << "In Shape::~Shape()\n";
    }

    void operator delete(Shape *, std::destroying_delete_t);
};

struct Triangle : Shape {
    Triangle() : Shape(TRIANGLE) {}

    ~Triangle() {
        std::cout << "In Triangle::~Triangle()\n";
    }
};

struct Square : Shape {
    Square() : Shape(SQUARE) {}

    ~Square() {
        std::cout << "In Square::~Square()\n";
    }
};

void Shape::operator delete(Shape *p, std::destroying_delete_t) {
    switch(p->kind) {
    case TRIANGLE:
        static_cast<Triangle *>(p)->~Triangle();
        break;
    case SQUARE:
        static_cast<Square *>(p)->~Square();
    }
    ::operator delete(p);
}

int main() {
    Shape *p = new Triangle;
    delete p;
    p = new Square;
    delete p;
}
```

It prints this:

```
In Triangle::~Triangle()
In Shape::~Shape()
In Square::~Square()
In Shape::~Shape()
```

(Note: GCC 11.1 and older will incorrectly call `Triangle::~Triangle()` instead of `Square::~Square()` when optimizations are enabled. See [comment 2 of bug #91859](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=91859#c2).)

Comment: "Destroying delete makes it safe to delete a derived class through a pointer to a base class even if it doesn't have a virtual destructor." - Isn't it rather that it puts the onus of making it safe on the implementer of the destroying delete? The function must now call the correct destructor *somehow*.

Comment: Can that also be used for implementing intrusive pointers, meaning actual deletion will only be done if no owners left?

Comment: @Deduplicator: Probably yes in practice but formally no, unless some further changes are made to the verbiage around object lifetime and valid operands to the `delete` operator.

Comment: GCC still shows a warning if one uses destroying operator delete: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=100861