# Why does clang have trouble with optimizing tail calls in destructors?

Tags: c++, clang, tail-recursion, tail-call-optimization, tail-call

Here is a simplified singly-linked list, where each node owns the next, along with a function for destroying the list:

```cpp
struct Node {
  Node* next = nullptr;

  ~Node() {
    delete next;
  }
};

void Destroy(Node* head) {
    delete head;
}
```

Clang 15.0.0 with `-O3` ([Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/TxEG8x4es)) gives recursive code for this that uses `call` instructions, i.e. no tail call recursion through `~Node` itself, only `operator delete(void*)`:

```
Destroy(Node*):                       # @Destroy(Node*)
        test    rdi, rdi
        je      .LBB0_1
        push    rbx
        mov     rbx, rdi
        call    Node::~Node() [base object destructor]
        mov     rdi, rbx
        pop     rbx
        jmp     operator delete(void*)@PLT                      # TAILCALL
.LBB0_1:
        ret
Node::~Node() [base object destructor]:                           # @Node::~Node() [base object destructor]
        push    rbx
        mov     rbx, qword ptr [rdi]
        test    rbx, rbx
        je      .LBB1_1
        mov     rdi, rbx
        call    Node::~Node() [base object destructor]
        mov     rdi, rbx
        pop     rbx
        jmp     operator delete(void*)@PLT                      # TAILCALL
.LBB1_1:
        pop     rbx
        ret
```

Here is an open-coded version of something similar:

```cpp
struct Node2 {
  Node2* next = nullptr;
};

void Destroy2(Node2* head) {
    auto* const next = head->next;
    delete head;

    if (next) {
      Destroy2(next);
    }
}
```

Even with `-01` clang turns the tail call into an efficient loop with O(1) stack frames involved for an arbitrary number of list nodes:

```
Destroy2(Node2*):                     # @Destroy2(Node2*)
        push    rbx
.LBB2_1:                                # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
        mov     rbx, qword ptr [rdi]
        call    operator delete(void*)@PLT
        mov     rdi, rbx
        test    rbx, rbx
        jne     .LBB2_1
        pop     rbx
        ret
```

I understand that compiler optimizations aren't guaranteed, but I'm surprised clang isn't able to do something more efficient with the basic `Destroy` case. It leads me to think that the key difference is in the fact that `Destroy2` is able to free the memory for `head` before it deals with `head->next`. But it seems to me that shouldn't matter unless `operator delete` is allowed to have some visible side effect.

Is there an important semantic difference between these two from the point of view of the abstract machine, preventing clang from optimizing the first case? If so, is there a way to make `~Node` more friendly to the optimizer so that I don't need to open-code a destroy function?

Comment: In the dtor-based version, you first recurse and then free current, in the `Destroy2`-version, you first delete and then recurse.

Comment: Yes, I did say that (in the second to last paragraph). The question is why clang isn't allowed to reorder the two operations.

Comment: I can only guess: `delete` might be considered observable externally.

Comment: Yep, that's my guess too. I'm hoping for a citation in the standard or similar, with details about what the compiler can assume about `delete`. I'm a bit surprised because I thought I remembered that in C calls to `malloc` and `free` can be elided (therefore the compiler can assume no side effects?), but this doesn't work even if I define an inline `operator delete` that uses `free`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's worth calling out explicitly something I alluded to in the question: that the operations in `~Node` are in the opposite order that they are in `Destroy2`. The destructor is something like this:

```cpp
// Pseudocode
~Node() {
  delete next;
  free(this);
}
```

So the question is why the compiler can't reverse those two operations, putting them in the same order as in `Destroy2` and allowing a tail call to `~Node` for `next`.

I can't say definitively that this is the answer, but [Richard Smith](https://github.com/zygoloid) points out that this could be because the compiler is limited in its ability to prove that anything preventing this would be UB. For example if there is a cycle in the list then maybe this could go wrong—a cycle would cause UB even for the existing code, but the compiler may not be able to see that. Perhaps more relevantly without an assumption about finite memory/object count (that the compiler probably doesn't make), the transformation isn't legal because the list may be unbounded without UB in the existing code.

---

As for what to do about it, Richard also points out that in C++20 we can use a [destroying `operator delete`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67595789/1505451) to reorder the operations ourselves, giving the effect of `Destroy2` with the convenience of just using `delete` like normal:

```cpp
struct Node {
  Node* next = nullptr;

  void operator delete(Node *p, std::destroying_delete_t) {
      Node *next = std::exchange(p->next, nullptr);
      ::delete p;
      delete next;
  }

  ~Node() {
    delete next;
  }
};
```

As of today the [generated code](https://godbolt.org/z/9vbTd49q5) is good for raw pointers and bad for `std::unique_ptr`, but the latter gets better if you [add `[[gnu::flatten]]`](https://godbolt.org/z/oox9xcWos) to the operator.