# Can classes place constraints on templates as well as the other way around?

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, c++-concepts

Imagine two smart pointer templates, `smart_ptr` and `smart_ptr_with_abort`.

- `smart_ptr` simply calls `delete` when the final reference to the object it holds is released
- `smart_ptr_with_abort` calls a class method `Abort()` before deleting the object.

My object `object` has an `Abort()` method that **must** be called before the object is deleted.

Using concepts I can make `smart_ptr_with_abort` fail to compile if it's being used with an object that doesn't have an `Abort()` method.

Is there a way to achieve the reverse situation, where `smart_ptr<object>` would fail to compile but `smart_ptr_with_abort<object>` would succeed?

Comment: You can't change how `std::smart_ptr` works.  This sounds like something that code review should be responsible for.

Comment: Care to post the code that works the opposite way? Or any code for that matter?

Comment: The same mechanism that you plan to use to make `smart_ptr_with_abort` not compile unless there is an `Abort` method, could be used to make `smart_ptr` not compile when there is in fact an `Abort` method. If that's what you want.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik that's why I've asked for the code :)

Comment: [Here's how](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257288/how-can-you-check-whether-a-templated-class-has-a-member-function) you write a trait that checks for an existence of a member function. You can negate this trait e.g. with [`std::negation`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/negation)

Comment: Why can't you just call `Abort()` in the destructor? If you want to support `Abort()` before destruction, you can just have a `bool`/`std::atomic_flag`/`std::once_flag` to make sure it is only called once. That way you can use it with "regular" smart pointers (and it will be much easier to use)

Comment: [How can you check whether a templated class has a member function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257288/how-can-you-check-whether-a-templated-class-has-a-member-function) and [Check if a class has a member function of a given signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/87372/check-if-a-class-has-a-member-function-of-a-given-signature)

Comment: *My object object has an Abort() method that must be called before the object is deleted*. Sounds like you want your smart pointers to use a custom deleter.

Comment: Yes, `requires` accepts a boolean expression, so you can negate your concept with `!`. But this smells of questionable design.

Comment: No offense, but this `smart_ptr_with_abort` interface sounds like a workaround that is solved already by using [a destroying `operator delete`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67595789/what-is-destroying-operator-delete-in-c20). Just define that for your class, and let it work with any smart pointer by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With more pondering on the question, I have chosen to approach the question differently thanks to [Elliott](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8658157/elliott).

The OP starts out this way and I quote:

> Imagine two smart pointer templates, `smart_ptr` and `smart_ptr_with_abort`

Forgive me for *my approach* but instead let’s imagine two `class`es that can take an arbitrary type upon construction.<sup>[1]</sup>

The constraint is that one `class A` must only take a type that has a method `Abort()` while another `class B` will only take a type that does not have the method `Abort()`. If `class A` is specialized with a type that doesn’t have the member function `Abort()`, the program fails to compile. And if `class B` takes a type that has the member function `Abort()`, the program also fails to compile.

> Using `concept`s I can make `smart_ptr_with_abort`<sup>[2]</sup> fail to compile if it's being used with an object that doesn't have an `Abort()` method.

Without your code I will write one approach here for posterity.

```
template<class T>
concept Abortable = requires(T t) { {t.Abort()}; };

template<Abortable T>
class A {/* implementation */}
```

> Is there a way to achieve the reverse situation, where `smart_ptr<object>`<sup>[3]</sup> would fail to compile but `smart_ptr_with_abort<object>` would succeed?

That is by using *”A Logical Negation expression”*. We can simply negate the other `concept` to produce a new `concept`.

```
template<class T>
concept NotAbortable = !Abortable<T>;

template<NotAbortable T>
class B {/* implementation */}
```

---

More on *Logical negation expression*:

> <sup>5</sup> [*Note:* A logical negation expression (7.6.2.1) is an atomic constraint; the negation operator is not treated as a logical operation on constraints. As a result, distinct negation constraint-expressions that are equivalent under 13.7.6.1 do not subsume one another under 13.5.4. Furthermore, if substitution to determine whether an atomic constraint is satisfied (13.5.1.2) encounters a substitution failure, the constraint is not satisfied, regardless of the presence of a negation operator. [*Example:*
>
> ```
> template <class T> concept sad = false;
>
> template <class T> int f1(T) requires (!sad<T>);
>
> template <class T> int f1(T) requires (!sad<T>) && true;
>                    int i1 = f1(42); // ambiguous, !sad<T> atomic constraint expressions (13.5.1.2) are not formed from the same expression
>
> template <class T> concept not_sad = !sad<T>;
>
> template <class T> int f2(T) requires not_sad<T>;
>
> template <class T> int f2(T) requires not_sad<T> && true;
>                    int i2 = f2(42); // OK, !sad<T> atomic constraint expressions both come from not_sad
>
> template <class T> int f3(T) requires (!sad<typename T::type>); 
>                    int i3 = f3(42); // error: associated constraints not satisfied due to substitution failure
>
> template <class T> concept sad_nested_type = sad<typename T::type>;
>
> template <class T> int f4(T) requires (!sad_nested_type<T>);
>                    int i4 = f4(42); // OK, substitution failure contained within sad_nested_type
> ```
>
> Here,
>
> `requires (!sad<typename T::type>)` requires that
> there is a nested type that is not sad, whereas
>
> `requires (!sad_nested_type<T>)` requires that there is no sad nested type. *— end example* ] *— end note* ]
>
> —-ISO/IEC JTC1 SC22 WG21 N4860 13.5.1.1

---

<sub>[1] This approach shields us from having our design criticized. I admit I did that in my first answer and any critic would do the same I believe.</sub>

<sub>[2] That will be `class A` in our illustration.</sub>

<sub>[3] That will be `class B` in our illustration.</sub>